# How to mask double (with Exp) in XamNumericEditor (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, double, infragistics, mask

I want to be able to validate user input in a field inside a Data Grid (XamDataPresenter).

The input suppose to be `double`, in the format `1.7E+3`

This is the filed settings in XAML:

```
     <igDP:Field Name="Factor" Label="Factor" Width="50">
         <igDP:Field.Settings>
             <igDP:FieldSettings EditorStyle="{StaticResource DoubleCell}" />
         </igDP:Field.Settings>
     </igDP:Field>
```

and this is the Style (with the mask):

```
     <Style x:Key="DoubleCell" TargetType="{x:Type igEditors:XamNumericEditor}" >
         <Setter Property="Mask" Value="{}{double}"/>
     </Style>
```

I don't know how to set the mask to be Double number with Exp format.

Comment: I think you need to set up a regex for it.

Comment: How to connect some regex to a mask ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example of a simple solution, not in XAML, but its working good (with `Double.Parse`)

```
public String Factor
{
    get { return m_Factor; }
    set 
    { 
        m_Factor = value;
        this.ValidateElement(..);
    }
}

public void ValidateElement(..)
{
        try
        {
            this.SetFieldDataError(null, ..);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(m_Factor))
            {
                m_Factor = Double.Parse(FactorInternal).ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            this.SetFieldDataError("some error", ..);
        }
}
```